# Mysql table performance problems on simple update/select (large table, many connections)

Tags: mysql

I've been playing with various approaches for about one week, always resulting in "crashing" my server through massive load during the test runs.

```
mysql> explain select id FROM task_jobs FORCE INDEX (index_update_get_work) WHERE customer_job_id=31 AND client_reserved=0  AND result_delivered=0 AND (assigned_instance is NULL)  LIMIT 10;
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table              | partitions | type | possible_keys         | key                   | key_len | ref                     | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | task_jobs | NULL       | ref  | index_update_get_work | index_update_get_work | 14      | const,const,const,const | 104226 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

To keep it generic: I have a table with millions of growing rows.
The table is providing work jobs to hundreds up to thousands of cloud instances at a time.

All those instances will query my table (up to 3000 queries at once) and ask to receive their work data.

There are a few hundred thousand of rows with "open jobs" but only 10-20 are handed out to one instance at a time.

My current approach which is most performant but still a big problem:

1. I make an UPDATE on LIMIT 10 rows WHERE customer_job_id=31 AND client_reserved=0  AND result_delivered=0 AND (assigned_instance is NULL)
   I guess the query is self explaining, it looks for unassigned jobs which have not delivered a result yet from a specific "job id".
   The query looks like the one in the beginning just UPDATE instead of SELECT.
2. now program logic chooses some of the delievered rows and makes a second update to finally assign them to the instance using WHERE id IN (x,x,x,x,x)

I am using this approach so I can fast "lock" 10 rows by updating them to be busy so the next instance can also lock another 10 rows, and so on.

This works fine and without any issues for 100 instances at a time, if I drive up the load to 500 instances the server gets locked up.
It fills the database connections with hundreds of LOCKed requests to update 10 rows taking 15 seconds eat (it was at 140 sec before optimization).

As you can see in the beginning, the SELECT (in reality it's an UPDATE SET client_reserved = 1, assigned_instance=$instance_id ) has to go through 100k rows (possibly more). 
Even if it just chooses 10 of them, it seems to examine every single job before it finishes and updates the first 10. At least EXPLAIN seems to tell that.

So basically my question is to find a better approach.
I need to grab out thousands of rows within a few seconds from thousands of distinct connections.
Every time I need to get a small number of rows out of the 100-500k available jobs/rows "WHERE customer_job_id=31 AND client_reserved=0  AND result_delivered=0 AND (assigned_instance is NULL)".

assigned_instance is a varchar (with index(1) for the NULL condition) the others are tinyint(1). I made an index combining all of them but it didn't really help.

**Update**
For clarification:
I am using the "UPDATE" because the API on the main server does not know if there are other simultanous requests "give me work".
So I used UPDATE on a number of rows to "reserve" them for the current instance.
As UPDATE is an "atomic" operation in SQL there is no risk that another request is served with the same jobs (race condition).

**Update question**
A general question: I use LIMIT 10
Why does it search through 100,000 results if 10 are enough ?
It makes no performance difference when I add ORDER BY RAND() where it really has to look through all 100k results and reorder them (same performance cost).
Why doesn't mysql just stop once it found 10 hits (that's what I hoped for with LIMIT 10 and by omitting any ORDER BY clauses)

Comment: For general question regarding LIMIT: MySQL retrieves all rows that satisfy the query then it discards everything minus LIMIT rows, starting at OFFSET. Why is this not better designed? Because it can't be, MySQL has to gather the rows, apply the ordering (at this point you collected everything that satisfies the query) and only after ordering is applied, you can return, say, 10 rows starting from beginning. LIMIT does not improve performance, it will simply reduce how many records are written to the socket.

Comment: @N.B. I understand when ordering but I tried omitting any ORDER BY.
In such a case mysql could ignore any ordering and just stop it's operation once LIMIT has been fulfilled. No ?

Comment: Not really. Even if you don't specify an order by clause, there exists an order in which it has to find return records. If this order is by primary key (the way it was written on disk) then it is possible to find only say, 10 records and stop. As I'm not sure if it indeed does that (I know it's a b**tch to develop something like that), I won't claim it's indeed doing it, but I know where you're coming from - we'd all like it if it behaved that way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so what you need is a task queue, which would store references to available jobs, which could be "popped" from the queue

## Task Queue

```
CREATE TABLE task_queue (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    task_job_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

You could VERY quickly "pop" x items from the table with something like this:

```
LOCK TABLES task_queue READ;
SELECT * FROM task_queue LIMIT x;
DELETE FROM task_queue LIMIT x;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

You could continue to write onto the end of the queue, with a cron running every minute to retrieve and queue new tasks matching your criteria:

```
SELECT id
FROM task_jobs
FORCE INDEX (index_update_get_work) 
WHERE customer_job_id = 31 
    AND client_reserved = 0  
    AND result_delivered = 0 
    AND assigned_instance IS NULL
    AND id NOT IN (SELECT task_job_id FROM task_queue);
```

## Single-Table Queue

Here's an idea for a single-table queue design:

You'll want to persist your queue index in the DB.  You could do this with a single-row table

```
CREATE TABLE queue_index (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Initialize it one time with your min id.

```
INSERT INTO queue_index (id)
SELECT MIN(id) FROM task_jobs
WHERE customer_job_id = 31 
    AND client_reserved = 0  
    AND result_delivered = 0 
    AND assigned_instance IS NULL;
```

You could "pop" x items from the table with something like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

SELECT @oldid = id FROM queue_index;

SELECT @newid = MAX(id)
FROM (
    SELECT id
    FROM task_jobs 
    WHERE id > @oldid
    LIMIT x
) AS j;

UPDATE queue_index SET id = @newid;

SELECT * FROM task_queue WHERE id <= @newid;

END TRANSACTION;
```

Then, any new task_jobs added will automatically be in-queue for assignment.

If the pointer moves beyond a given task, and you then want to schedule it for assignment again, you should delete the record and reinsert it at the end of the list.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
But how does that solve that for example 1000 requests come in at the same second ?
If I use "select" I'd get roughtly 1000 similar rows.

I was using the UPDATE because that way it's impossible that simultanous requests receive the same rows, the issue is that each UPDATE considers too many rows at once.

The problem is that the API which listens for incoming "give me work" requests does not know about all the other instances also asking for work. I needed an "atomic" approach to get a few rows without risk to give out the same job twice.

Comment: Got it.  I misunderstood the problem.  I'll consider it further and let you know if I have any ideas.

Comment: I am already so deep in the issue that I explain it bad;)
Anyway you made me think in other directions.
I just played around and found that searching for an "id" to start is a fast operation and limiting the update to a smaller number of "ids" is 10 times faster than using LIMIT only.
So maybe I can solve it by finding the lowest possible ID and then only searching through the next ~500 IDs using the same UPDATE

Comment: @John - that's definitely a possibility.  I updated my answer anyway, to show the use a queue table.  If you could guarantee that jobs are assignable in an incremental order, that would make this even faster (i.e. no "old" jobs get unassigned at a later date).

Comment: @John - Another idea, is if your task_jobs get "unassigned", you could simply delete them and reinsert at the end of the task_jobs list, so you could use the single table as a queue, and simply update the queue pointer, so you know where the next assignable job is.

Comment: I'll accept your response, I guess a small queue which might be filled efficiently in the background could solve the issue easily.
I solved it another way (second answer), in the end also thanks to you cause you made me think in a new direction ;)

Comment: @John - See the single-table queue design below.  I think this might be your simplest solution.

Comment: Glad you found a solution to your problem!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution, reducing the performance cost from "20,000" to "0"
It seems like mysql can completely get it out of indexes that way which was impossible before.

```
$id=select MIN(id) from task_jobs where customer_job_id=31 AND assigned_time is NULL) AND assigned_time is NULL;

select id FROM task_jobs WHERE customer_job_id=31 AND client_reserved=0  AND
 result_delivered=0 AND (assigned_instance is NULL) AND 
id >= $id LIMIT 10;
```

As jobs were added sequenzial I could just find the lowest id (the subquery) and limit mysql to start searching there.
Suddenly the cost goes down from 20k to 0-10;